# How do I migrate data from one Cassandra database to another?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I have two Cassandra databases in two different hosts. Both have tables with the exact same definition. How do I migrate data from one to the other?

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(App.APP_NAME)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", App.CASSANDRA_HOST)
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "user")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "pass")
    .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "3600");
SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaRDD<EventLog> logs = javaFunctions(sparkContext)
    .cassandraTable("xyz", "event_log", mapRowTo(EventLog.class));
javaFunctions(logs).writerBuilder("xyz", "event_log", mapToRow(EventLog.class)).saveToCassandra();
sparkContext.stop();
```

In my Java code, I have read from the original DB and want to use the `writerBuilder` to write it into another DB. Where do I put the second DB's config and how do I write it there?

Comment: Why do you want to use Spark for your purposes? It's possible to do it with Cassandra features: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/migrating.html

Comment: @maxteneff I am also doing some filtering. The docs don't show how to move from one db to another in different hosts. It's only from DB to file and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/2.0.0/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions$WriterBuilder), there is a method

```
def withConnector(connector: CassandraConnector): WriterBuilder
```

Which you can call to pass in a different CassandraConnector object with the destination cluster information. This returns a new `WriterBuilder` which you would call `saveToCassandra` on.